# TCSH command logger

Tags: shell, logging, tcsh

Is there a way to log history(and save it in .history file) in tcsh every time a command is entered in the shell ? Something like the solution given here for bash:
[Bash Command Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193441/bash-command-logger)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There are several shell variables (those specified by the `set` command, and not environment variables) that control how this works:

- *history* specifies how many commands will be remembered in the current shell
- *histfile* names the file to save the history to (which is **~/.history** by default)
- *savehist* which specifies that the history of commands will be recorded to the history file

For example, you might put the following in your `.tcshrc` file:

```
set history = 1000  # remember 1000 commands
set savehist = 100  # write the last 100 commands to $histfile
set histfile = "~/.my-history"
```

Also, according to the manual page, doing a `history -S` will write the current history (as controlled by the above variables).

NB: the `history -S` didn't seem to work well on Mac OSX's 10.8 for me; it hung the shell